# Iron router routes from db

Tags: mongodb, meteor, iron-router

I try to load my routes from db. My collection schema for routes is:

```
AsideMenu.attachSchema(
new SimpleSchema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        denyUpdate: true
    },
    path: {
        type: String,
        denyUpdate: true
    },
    controller: {
        type: String,
        denyUpdate: true
    }
})
```

);

I defined also a method for publish and subscribe and everything works well, i can get on client all the records on which he has access, but i cant get the router to register them.

```
    _.map(menuRoutes, function (route) {
    Router.route(route.path,
        {
            name: route.name,
            controller: route.controller,
        })
})
```

When I access in client console:

```
console.log(Router.routes) I get []
```

And if i print it in server console i get all routes:

```
I20150227-19:02:47.753(2)?   { [Function]
I20150227-19:02:47.753(2)?     getName: [Function],
I20150227-19:02:47.753(2)?     findControllerConstructor: [Function],
I20150227-19:02:47.754(2)?     createController: [Function],
I20150227-19:02:47.754(2)?     setControllerParams: [Function],
I20150227-19:02:47.754(2)?     dispatch: [Function],
I20150227-19:02:47.754(2)?     path: [Function],
I20150227-19:02:47.754(2)?     url: [Function],
I20150227-19:02:47.755(2)?     params: [Function],
I20150227-19:02:47.755(2)?     get: [Function],
I20150227-19:02:47.755(2)?     post: [Function],
I20150227-19:02:47.755(2)?     put: [Function],
I20150227-19:02:47.755(2)?     delete: [Function],
I20150227-19:02:47.756(2)?     options: 
I20150227-19:02:47.756(2)?      { name: 'calendar.index',
I20150227-19:02:47.756(2)?        controller: 'CalendarController',
I20150227-19:02:47.756(2)?        data: [Function],
I20150227-19:02:47.756(2)?        mount: false },
I20150227-19:02:47.757(2)?     _actionStack: { _stack: [], length: 0 },
I20150227-19:02:47.757(2)?     _beforeStack: { _stack: [], length: 0 },
I20150227-19:02:47.757(2)?     _afterStack: { _stack: [], length: 0 },
I20150227-19:02:47.757(2)?     _methods: {},
I20150227-19:02:47.758(2)?     _path: '/calendar',
I20150227-19:02:47.758(2)?     handler: 
I20150227-19:02:47.758(2)?      { options: [Object],
I20150227-19:02:47.758(2)?        mount: false,
I20150227-19:02:47.758(2)?        method: false,
I20150227-19:02:47.759(2)?        where: 'client',
I20150227-19:02:47.759(2)?        name: 'calendar.index',
I20150227-19:02:47.759(2)?        path: '/calendar',
I20150227-19:02:47.759(2)?        compiledUrl: [Object],
I20150227-19:02:47.759(2)?        handle: [Circular],
I20150227-19:02:47.917(2)?        route: [Circular] },
```

I want to know if this is possible because i couldnt find any example with this aproach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this should be possible. I have a similar setup working just fine, the only difference being that I create the routes from a static array, not a db query. But that should make a difference.

This works for me, when executed during load:

```
_.each(routes, function(foo, route) {
    Router.map(function () {
        this.route(route, {
            path: route,
            action: function() { ... }
        });
    });
});
```

Where/when are you executing the `_.map` code you showed?

Comment: From a static array it works for me too(i tested it), i think the problem is from subscription, iron-router is not waiting for it on client :(

Comment: @MariusDarila did you have a `waitOn`?

Comment: Yes, i have it on client on router global config

Comment: I don't think that can work. Think about it: the client code gets executed on page load. At that time the db sync hasn't happened yet, but you already need to know whether a given route (your current URL) needs to exist or not. You are putting the cart before the horse. could you use server side routes instead? Those should work.

Comment: @ChristianFritz yep, it cant be done for client routes

Answer (score 0):

Iron router runs a reactive computation, but at the time your subscription to your route definitions collection is not ready. So if you put that block in your ready callback which is:

```
Meteor.subscribe('router-data-publication', function() {
  /* construct your routes here*/
});
```

or, you can do something safer, but essentially the same, using a handle within a Tracker and checking .ready() on the handler.